LAMMPS: Start NVE simulation with different initial energies
I am new to LAMMPS and am using it to conduct microcanonical (NVE) MD simulations. I am able to run NVE simulations using the fix NVE command, but I want to start a series of simulations in parallel but each with a different total energy being held constant in the system.
I was curious how can I start simulations at different fixed total energy values for NVE simulations.

Calculate the desired kinetic energies, corresponding temperatures, and then use the velocity command to impose that temperature before starting. (I am starting with a comment in case you have further questions.)

I see. I was just wondering if there is parameter in lammps nve runs such that I could just fix the total energy for the total run.
So I guess the procedure is to convert energy to temperature first and run simulation by scaling the initial velocities to correspond to the energies I am interested in as you mentioned by doing velocity all create {temp} 825577 dist gaussian., say.
